# How to dispatch a change action in redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Just learning redux-form and from within my component I am trying to change a fieldname by code:

```
Import React from 'react'
import { connect, dispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form'



let SelectingFormValuesForm = props => {

  const changeStuff = (props) => {
    dispatch(change('selectingFormValues', 'firstName', 'Bertje'))
  }

  const {
    favoriteColorValue,
    fullName,
    handleSubmit,
    hasEmailValue,
    pristine,
    reset,
    submitting,
    change
  } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="firstName"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="First Name"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="lastName"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Last Name"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="hasEmail">Has Email?</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="hasEmail"
            id="hasEmail"
            component="input"
            type="checkbox"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      {hasEmailValue && (
        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <div>
            <Field
              name="email"
              component="input"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      <div>
        <label>Favorite Color</label>
        <div>
          <Field name="favoriteColor" component="select">
            <option />
            <option value="#ff0000">Red</option>
            <option value="#00ff00">Green</option>
            <option value="#0000ff">Blue</option>
          </Field>
        </div>
      </div>
      {favoriteColorValue && (
        <div
          style={{
            height: 80,
            width: 200,
            margin: '10px auto',
            backgroundColor: favoriteColorValue
          }}
        />
      )}
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
          Submit {fullName}
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={changeStuff}>
          Change first name
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

// The order of the decoration does not matter.

// Decorate with redux-form
SelectingFormValuesForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'selectingFormValues',// a unique identifier for this form
  change: reduxForm.change,
  dispatch:reduxForm.dispatch
})(SelectingFormValuesForm)

// Decorate with connect to read form values
const selector = formValueSelector('selectingFormValues') // <-- same as form name
SelectingFormValuesForm = connect(state => {

  //debugger
  // can select values individually
  const hasEmailValue = selector(state, 'hasEmail')
  const favoriteColorValue = selector(state, 'favoriteColor')
  // or together as a group
  const { firstName, lastName } = selector(state, 'firstName', 'lastName')
  return {
    hasEmailValue,
    favoriteColorValue,
    fullName: `${firstName || ''} ${lastName || ''}`
  }
})(SelectingFormValuesForm)

export default SelectingFormValuesForm
```

When I click this 'change first name' button this gets executed. I imported the change action from redux-form. Why am I getting this error:

> react-dom.development.js:283 Uncaught TypeError: (0 ,
>   _reactRedux.dispatch) is not a function
>           at changeStuff (SelectingFormValuesForm.js:20)
>           at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:143)
>           at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:193)

Comment: A potential fix to your problem would be to pass onClick={changeStuff(change)} would it not? It seems that "change" is not defined in your current changeStuff function. Also, any reason you are using redux-form over formik? I've made the switch a week ago myself and it's been worth it so far.

Comment: How would changing a formvalue go in formik? Easier?

Comment: The API provides a function called [setFieldValue](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean-void). Also worth reading is [this](https://matwrites.com/redux-form-is-dead/) and [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#fully-fledged-solutions), unless you have a very very good reason to store your form data in the redux-store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several ways of changing the field value, but here's how you can do it with `change`:

1. `import { change } from 'redux-form';`
2. Add `change` to a `mapDispatchToProps` object.
3. Add `mapDispatchToProps` into `connect` as the second argument (if `mapStateToProps` is not needed, then it'd be `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)`.
4. Call `this.props.change` or `props.change` with a `formname`, `fieldname` and `value`.
5. *Optional* -- Use a `PureComponent` when calling secondary form actions -- easier to read and easier to test.

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/r5zz36lqnn

Comment: Thanks for that @Matt . Another question, how can I getformvalues from a form? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435964/how-to-get-formvalues-in-handlechange

Comment: Your example is great but I cannot get it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55440059/how-to-change-a-field-in-a-redux-form