# How to get formvalues in handlechange?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

In my form I have an onChange event on one of the formfields:

```
        <div>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <div>
                <Field
                    name="lastName"
                    component="input"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Last Name"
                    onChange={() => this.handleChange()}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
```

When handleChange gets fired I want to get the formvalues :

```
handleChange(){
        //do calculation
        console.log('handlechange',this.props.values)        
    }
```

At the moment I am getting this.props.values = undefined? How can I get the formvalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You'll need to create a custom `input`.
2. You'll need to intercept and update redux's `input.onChange` function.
3. *Optional* -- If you want other form values to influence this value, then utilize reduxForm's `formSelector` with `react-redux`'s `connect`'s `mapStateToProps` to access formProps within the component in `this.props` (the working example below already includes this functionality)

**components/CustomInput.js**

```
import React from "react";

const CustomInput = ({
  // we'll intercept redux's "onChange" func, while leaving the other 
  // input props as is in "inputProps"
  input: { onChange, ...inputProps }, 
  // the "handleChange" func below is the parent func that will handle input changes
  handleChange, 
  // "rest" contains any additional properties (className, placeholder, type ...etc)
  ...rest 
}) => (
  // we spread out the "inputProps" and the "rest" of the props, then we add
  // an "onChange" event handler that returns the "event" and the 
  // input's "onChange" func to our "handleChange" parent func
  <input {...inputProps} {...rest} onChange={e => handleChange(e, onChange)} />
);

export default CustomInput;
```

**containers/Form.js**

```
class ControlledFormValue extends PureComponent { 

  // this parent func will handle updates through the "event.target.value"; 
  // the value can be changed/altered and then passed to the input's
  // "onChange" func to update the field
  handleChange = ({ target: { value } }, onChange) => {
    // this will alter the value by adding a "-" after each input update
    onChange(`${value}-`);
    setTimeout(() => console.log(this.props.values), 500);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <div>
            <Field
              className="uk-input"
              name="firstName"
              component={CustomInput}
              type="text"
              placeholder="First Name"
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        ...etc
     </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/lx1r4yjwy7

Comment: I was looking for a solution with getFormValues because I am using a FieldArray. The formvalues is a list of rows with for each row an object representing the row.  I actually simplified the question .

Comment: Updated example above and the codesandbox. Change an input and it'll print out the current form values. All you need to do is add `getFormValues` to `mapStateToProps`. Just note that `mapStateToProps` is `asynchronous`, so you'll have to wait for updates (hence the `setTimeout`).